# Eclipse Web Development Plugin to Sync with Remote Server

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm using Eclipse Helios to develop a PHP/Smarty project.
Is there a plugin that can help me easily publish code to the web server?
Something like setting up the location of the web root once, then I can just right-click on a file to send.
Currently, I'm using FileZilla to send my code to the web server.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Thanks,
Kenneth

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Remote System Explorer](http://tmober.blogspot.com/2006/11/remote-system-explorer-10-is-released.html) (RSE) from [Target Management](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/) (DSDP/TP) project. Look at the [Getting Started] page.